# Assign value to double array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have an issue assigning values to an array of arrays to add duplicates into the same values. Code is as following:

```
if( isset($rowsarray) && 0 < count($rowsarray) ) {
    foreach ( $rowsarray as $rowt ) {
        if( $version == $rowt[0] ) {
            $rowt[1] += $success;
            $rowt[2] += $failure;
            $noDuplicate = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
if( true == $noDuplicate) {
    $rowsarray[] = array($version, $success, $failure);
}
```

So if it's the first occurence of a version I just add it, otherwise I just increas the success and failure rate in the array. I have tried foreach ( $rowsarray as $key => $rowt ) without success as the "internal" array doesnt seem to be affected here. I am total new to php so I guess it's a rather simple solution but for now it takes only the first version access and all the other is inreased inside the loop but not outside it.

Comment: What does `$rowsarray` look like?

Comment: `true == $noDuplicate`, `0 < count($rowsarray)`, WHY? WHY ARE YOU DOING THIS?

Comment: the true == $noDuplicate check is that I dont want to add it another time if I updated it, the 0 < count($rowsarray) is that I populate it after the check (rather silly I know, but it's a quick hack for now) so I have no reason to check an empty array. I assumed that isset is if the variable exist or not, nothing if it is populated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to modify a temporary array created by foreach(), which means `$rowt` is trashed/replaced on every iteration. You can work around it with a reference or a modified foreach:

```
foreach ( $rowsarray as &$rowt ) {
                        ^----
        $rowt[1] += $success;
```

or, less troublesome:

```
foreach($rowsarray as $key => $rowt) {
    $rowsarray[$key][1] += $success;
```

Comment: Hmm, both solutions throws me Undefined offset on the assignments. The second solution seems to be less frequented by errors but still won't take.

Comment: nm me, if i read correctly the solution and did what it said $rowsarray[$key][1] += $success; instead of $rowt[$key][1] += $success; it would have worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify this check with:

```
if( isset($rowsarray) && 0 < count($rowsarray) ) {
```

with

```
 if( ! empty( $rowsarray ) ){
```

And then,

```
foreach ( $rowsarray as $key => $rowt ) {
    if( $version == $rowt[0] ) {
        $rowsarray[$key][1] += $success;
        $rowsarray[$key][2] += $failure;
```